# CORs error when calling a deployed edge function in supabase from the browser

Tags: javascript, supabase, deno

I have an edge function deployed with the following code:

```
import { serve } from "server"
import * as cryptojs from "crypto-js";

import { config } from "dotenv";

// Load the environment variables from .env file
await config();

const corsHeaders = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'authorization, x-client-info, apikey, content-type',
}

serve(async (req) => {
  // This is needed if you're planning to invoke your function from a browser.
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return new Response('ok', { headers: corsHeaders })
  }

  try {

    ...
    ... 
    ...

    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify(data), {
        status: 200,
        headers: { ...corsHeaders, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      }
    )
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response(
      JSON.stringify({ error: error.message || error.toString() }), {
        status: 500,
        headers: { ...corsHeaders, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      }
    );
  }
})
```

As you can see, `corsHeaders` is applied to enable invocation from the browser which is called using the supabase libary:

```
const response = await supabase.functions.invoke(
                "retrieve-payment-link", {
                    body: {
                        id: payment_link_id,
                    }
                }
            );
```

and was deployed with the following command:
 `npx supabase functions deploy retrieve-payment-link --import-map supabase/functions/import_map.json` and yet I'm still having this error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource`. Running in local doesn't have any issues, only in production. How do I fix this?

Comment: I think there is an error in production that prevents this code from loading. A dependency problem most likely. Have you seen the logs? Can you add a log statement?

Comment: please add the **exact** error you are receiving - I suspect your request will result in requiring an actual host in `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` (i.e. not `*`) - but it's not clear from the code as I can't see what the error states

Comment: On the frontend side I'm getting this `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource`. Upon checking logs, I'm getting this on invocation: `CPU execution time exceeded`

Comment: please add the exact error you are receiving *to the question* - where it should've been in the first place :p

Comment: Do you want to remove all the code inside `try` except for the return statement so that you can isolate the issue? From the `CPU execution time exceeded` error message, it seems like your function execution is taking some time.

Answer (score 0):

In local, the Docker Containers were not updated after the Supabase CLI update. Plase run `supabase stop` and `supabase start` to restart and download the containers again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).